# Framework for Browser toolbar

Tags: browser, frameworks, toolbar

Is there a framework I can use to make cross-browser toolbar?

To make my self more clear : I want something like this but for browsers
http://www.phonegap.com/

As you can see , it uses a common technology (HTML+CSS+JS) to make cross-platform mobile apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://kangoextensions.com/
for cross-browser extension development

Comment: anyone know the cost of the license?

Comment: http://kangoextensions.com/kango.html "Kango is free for open source non-profitable projects. To learn more about the commercial license please contact us." - Guess you need to write them.